# BLE data string handling in Thunkable

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, codeblocks, thunkable

I am trying to make an app for health monitoring system. Stuck up with BLE data string receiving and displaying on screen. Want a particular picture to show up after receiving a number say 63.Am I missing some thing ? Can some one help me please.
Thanks

I want a particular picture to show up based on the number received depicting various status.

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! I understand that Thunkable is just drag and drop and sharing your current code/setup might not be so easy. But it is nearly impossible to help you without seeing your code/setup